# Noun for “threatening with punishment”

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a *single word* that can be used in the following sentence:

“The incessant _____ become unbearable for him.”

Essentially what I’m looking for is a single word for “threats of punishment”.

“Intimidation” came to mind, but I’m not sure if it’s the best word to convey what I’m trying to say.

Comment: Explain yourself. Who is threatening punishment? Police, God, or bullies?

Comment: "the incessant threat of punishment"is fine. Probably better than anything else.

Answer (score -1):

**bullying** (n.)

> The repeated use of threats or violence in an attempt to harm or
> intimidate others [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/bullying)

> The act of intimidating a weaker person to make them do something
> [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/bullying)

---

> The Legion began recruiting workers in late 1932, and by 1933 they
> were **bullying** coffee shop owners into employing legionaries and
> organising boycotts of minority-owned business. [Marco Bresciani;
> *Conservatives and Right Radicals in Interwar Europe*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Conservatives_and_Right_Radicals_in_Inte/5qoLEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=bullying%20shopowners&pg=PT216&printsec=frontcover)

> A national survey in Malta found that 61% of boy bullies reported
> **bullying** others with physical violence compared with 30% of girl bullies... [UNESCO; *School Violence and Bullying*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/School_violence_and_bullying/dXX2DQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=bullying%20threat%20of%20violence&pg=PA18&printsec=frontcover)